# Eclipse run different maven goals on several projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have few maven projects while using Eclipse Neon,

I need to run different goals on different projects to be execute as a sequence/

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418515/how-to-run-many-maven-goals-from-eclipse-in-one-click) that I can't, or an [answer for same goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797886/single-command-to-build-all-eclipse-maven-projects-in-current-workspace)

Example of usage: call `clean install` of project A and B, `clean install -X` on project C and then `clean install tomcat7:run-war -X` on project D

Comment: `clean install`and `clean install -X`are the same goals. You just active the debug logs with `-X`

Comment: @jhamon yes, the main issue in project D, `clean install tomcat7:run-war -X`

Comment: If you don't need to run it in eclipse, you can do that with a shell script

Comment: @jhamon can you answer how it can be done in script? (and why it's not working in eclipse)

Comment: For Eclipse Oxygen you can create Launch groups, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103551/2834978).

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Now that I upgrade eclipse I can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to run maven using command line.

Basic format is :

```
mvn [goal [goal2 [goal3] ...]]
```

`clean` and `install` are standard goals.

`tomcat7:run-war` is a plugin goal.

You surely have a `<plugin>` section in the pom.xml setting the property for this goal. You can find all other goals for tomcat7 plugin here: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

You need to get in each of your projects folder and run the command with approriate goals:

```
cd <project_A_pom_directory>
mvn clean install
cd <project_B_pom_directory>
mvn clean install -X
cd <project_C_pom_directory>
mvn clean install tomcat7:run-war -X
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, can you refer to why it can't be executed in eclipse? Is it a known issue of plugin? Is there an open enhancement?

Comment: It can be executed in eclipse on a single project: you can set the goals in the `Run Configuration` panel. But you can't run multiple maven builds in sequence with different goals in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If you install a command line Maven, you can call `mvn clean install` from your shell or cmd. Then you can write a sh or bat file that navigates into the right folders and calls the mvn command.

If you generally want to build all the projects, think about multi-module projects. If this is too much refactoring, you can also define a separate project (as reactor project) that includes your four projects as modules. Running `mvn clean install` on the whole project would then run the command on all the including modules. In the multi-module setting, it is unfortunately not possible to run *diffferent* Maven goals for the different modules (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4112696/927493). You either need to call Maven twice (with a different list of modules) or add the tomcat goal to your install phase in the relevant module.

Comment: what about `tomcat7:run-war`?

Comment: `mvn clean install tomcat7:run-war`

Comment: Have a look at the Maven documentation about plugins: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html

Comment: @jhamon I didn't find something relevant, can you give an answer describing your solution?

Comment: On the first link you have an example on how to run a custom goal (more info on mavan comand can be found there). You can find the complete goals for tomcat7 here: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: @jhamon I'm executing maven goals, but I want to execute different goals on different projects in 1 call of maven, e.g. `clean` project A and `install` on project B

Comment: @user7294900 AFAIK you cannot include different projects in one maven call.

Comment: @JFMeier as you suggested, it's possible in `multi-module project`

Comment: You can run Maven goals (and phases) on all modules (or a subset), but with one Maven run, you can only run _the same_ set of goals/phases, e.g. you can run `clean install` on all modules, but for running the tomcat goal, you need a separate Maven call.